# What are these regular flights to India amid the ban on international flights?

Tags: india, covid-19

India has currently [banned](https://dgca.gov.in/digigov-portal/jsp/dgca/homePage/viewPDF.jsp?page=topHeader/COVID/Circular(26June2020).pdf) international flights to reduce the spread of Covid-19. How and why is British Airways operating regular flights to various destinations in India like [Delhi](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ba142) and [Mumbai](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ba138)?

EDIT: I'm aware that the order allows exemptions, but as far as I can tell, that route is not available to book on BA in the [immediate future](https://www.britishairways.com/travel/booking/public/en_gb/#/flightList?origin=LHR&destination=BOM&outboundDate=2020-07-15&inboundDate=2020-07-17&adultCount=1&youngAdultCount=0&childCount=0&infantCount=0&cabin=M&ticketFlexibility=LOWEST&journeyType=RTFLT&source=false).

Comment: The order explicitly allows for exceptions, so presumably these are among them?

Comment: Point no 2 of the order you have linked to explains why some flights are allowed. Did you read the order?

Comment: I did read the order, the question is because even though there appear to be daily flights to Mumbai, they're not actually available for booking on BA's website for any date in the immediate future: https://www.britishairways.com/travel/booking/public/en_gb/#/flightList?origin=LHR&destination=BOM&outboundDate=2020-07-15&inboundDate=2020-07-17&adultCount=1&youngAdultCount=0&childCount=0&infantCount=0&cabin=M&ticketFlexibility=LOWEST&journeyType=RTFLT&source=false

Comment: They are repatriation flights - and have been a source of tension between India and the US recently.  To get on them you need to talk to your government about repatriation.

Comment: Those flights also exist so that their pilots can retain their qualifications; otherwise, they'll require extensive training again.

Comment: So I had booked one such flight in Nov (YYZ-LHR-DEL-BOM) on BA and return in Dec but after having a word with BA, I got to know that they will fly you into India but they are only suppose to carry people between UK-India-UK since they are repatriation flights. So on my way back to YYZ, they will not allow me to board at BOM since I cannot take a repatriation flight to Canada from India. I know it sounds weird but I had to cancel my ticket (for an evoucher) because of this.

Comment: @BhushanKale is this because the requirements for "Outbound flights from India" on the linked page only allow Indian nationals to travel to the UK, and not further? Does this mean Indian nationals with Canadian permanent resident status can't travel to India and back? 
https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/incident/coronavirus/entry-requirements

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.